# Android - How to post a state with Facebook 3.0 SDK

Tags: android, facebook, post, message

With the Facebook SDK examples I'm able to login with Facebook, but now I need to post a message on the wall, I don't understand how to do this.
This is my code
public class CondividiSuFacebookActivity extends Activity{

```
  public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
  {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.facebook_condividi);


      String msg = (String)getIntent().getStringExtra("message");


      // start Facebook Login
      Session.openActiveSession(this, true, new Session.StatusCallback() 
      {

          // callback when session changes state

          public void call(Session session, SessionState state, Exception exception) 
          {
                if (session.isOpened()) 
                {

                    // make request to the /me API
                    Request.executeMeRequestAsync(session, new Request.GraphUserCallback() 
                    {

                        // callback after Graph API response with user object
                        public void onCompleted(GraphUser user, Response response) 
                        {
                            if (user != null) 
                            {
                                TextView welcome = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.welcome);
                                welcome.setText("Hello " + user.getName() + "!");
                            }
                        }
                    });
                }
          }
    });
  }


  public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
      super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
      Session.getActiveSession().onActivityResult(this, requestCode, resultCode, data);
  }



 }
```

I have found this function:

```
 Request.newStatusUpdateRequest(session, "Hello!", new Request.Callback() {

public void onCompleted(Response response) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

}
 });
```

But I don't understand how to use it. Any suggestions? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you take a look at the following StackOverflow question.

[Posting on facebook wall with sdk 3.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13290047/posting-on-facebook-wall-with-sdk-3-0)

Please ensure you read the answer to the question for the complete solution. The code in the question asked should still help you out.

Comment: Thanks you Richard, now I'm study the Facebook SDK example, in particular this FriendPickerApplication